# How do I pass additional arguments in wxperl EVT_BUTTON

Tags: c++, perl, wxwidgets, wxperl

I am trying to pass arguments to a perl subroutine which processes an wxPerl EVT_BUTTON event. I understand that when I use:

```
EVT_BUTTON($frame, $button, \&onClick);
```

I will have access to $frame and $button and its functions in `onClick`. However, I am trying to get the subroutine to read additional arguments, mainly the value/status of various other `Wx::CheckBox` values.

The only way I see this working is by using global variables and get `onClick` to read them, but I want to reuse `onClick` somewhere else, and using global vars is my least favorite option.

I've tried various things, which failed, for instance:

```
EVT_BUTTON($frame, $button, \&onClick(arg1,arg2));
```

I think the solution lies in the understanding of how Perl reference work, as we are passing `\&onClick` with the `\&` indicator in front. But I lack knowledge in that aspect of Perl...

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c++`?

Comment: I thought since wxWidget is originally written in C++, it is then related, sorry of it's not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
EVT_BUTTON($frame, $button, sub{ onClick($arg1,$arg2) });
```

it gives reference to anon subroutine, which calls then `onClick` sub, and it is equivalent to:

```
my $subref = sub{ onClick($arg1,$arg2) };
EVT_BUTTON($frame, $button, $subref);
```

Comment: Wow.. that actually worked! Thanks!
Can you explain the logic behind this solution?

Comment: The anonymous subroutine that access lexical variables ($arg1, $arg2) outside its scope is called a closure.